# RAM leaks on stl containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl, set

I have a RAM limit on my project, as it contains a lot of data manipulation . The problem is, I noticed that calling `std::set<std::pair<int64_t, int64_t>>::clear()` does not actually free any memory. The code for reproducing the problem:

```
std::set<std::pair<int64_t, int64_t>> stltest;
for (size_t i=1; i<=250000; i++)
{
    stltest.insert({i, i});
}
std::cout << " "; // place for a breakpoint
stltest.clear();
std::cout << " "; // place for a breakpoint
```

On ubuntu 20.04, standart c++ compiler this thing takes 17,7 MB and it doesn't give it back. Probably `clear()` just sets `size()` to zero, but does nothing with contents, which is weird. Am I dumb or am I dumb? Can I get the memory back, I really need it.

Edit: Tried to manually create new and delete after and still can't get my memory back.

Comment: Memory is usually never returned to the OS. The OS allocated meory in large chunks to the memory management library of the language. In C++ the application then uses the memory management library (view new/delete) but the library retains all the memory so it can be potentially re-used by other objects. So it is not leaked and will be reused by other objects. This is done for efficiency. Try building the `set` again after the `clear()` and your memory usage will not change.

Comment: @MartinYork, Thank you, I will run some tests and if what you're saying is true, the problem is not a problem anymore. Too bad i can't upvote comments.

Comment: Consider putting the relevant code in a 'local' scope; i.e., `{ ... }` ; this will ensure the destructor for `stltest` is called. That still doesn't *guarantee* anything about how C++ `new` / `delete` operators are implemented, or their (typical) underlying implementation based on C dynamic memory management: `malloc`, `free`, etc. Finally, there's the process / kernel interface that may allocate / release 'pages' on some platforms - and this may be contingent on memory pressure, caching, etc. In short - you are probably measuring the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Probably clear() just sets size() to zero, but does nothing with contents

No. It destroys the elements and deallocates their memory.

> Can I get the memory back

Sure, if you implement your own `malloc` and replace the standard one.

In practice no, that's not a useful goal.

> I really need it.

What do you think you need if for? Are you going to use it to create more objects? Because that is exactly the purpose for which the the implementation of `malloc` retains the memory.

Comment: I need the memory elsewhere, this buffer is not supposed to be used anymore, but retains the memory until program termination(not even it's own destructor)

Comment: @grango Describe "elsewhere" in more detail.

Comment: @grango `elsewhere` in the same application? Then you are fine the memory will be reused.

Answer (score 1):

You can either let `stltest` go out of scope, or

```
{
    std::set<std::pair<int64_t, int64_t>> reclaim_memory;
    stltest.swap(reclaim_memory);
}
```

in a new scope (so the brackets are important) so that the allocated memory
gets freed when `reclaim_memory` goes out of scope.

Comment: This was a common idiom used in place of `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` (with vectors) before C++11, normally written as `std::set<std::pair<int64_t, int64_t>>().swap(stltest)` (so you don't need the extra scope)

Comment: I dont think that rally makes sense with `set`. It does not use large chunks of pre-allocated memory that are retained.

Comment: @Artyer - in any case, `std::vector<...>::shrink_to_fit` is a *non-binding* request.

Comment: @MartinYork That depends on the implementation, it very well could, e.g. using a deque-like structure.

Answer (score 0):

On cppreference, it isn't really specified with much detail, what goes on during a `clear()`.... For vectors, cppreference states that the capacity remains unchanged, so it destroys but does not deallocate. And looking briefly through the header files on my clang install, set is also just destroying the objects, no deallocation seems to occur. This is however **not** a memory leak.

I believe this is the underlying function used...

```
template <class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Allocator>
void
__tree<_Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>::clear() _NOEXCEPT
{
    destroy(__root());
    size() = 0;
    __begin_node() = __end_node();
    __end_node()->__left_ = nullptr;
}
```

As there's no `shrink_to_fit()` for sets, easiest option is as others mentioned. Letting it go out of scope.